# Trouble creating a folder then creating files within the folder

Tags: java, file, directory

Hi I'm having a problem creating a folder in which every file I create in my for each loop will be placed. It is a basic problem but I can't seem to see it, any help would be much appreciated!

```
Scanner inputScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter location for output folder to be built..");
    String filePath=inputScan.next();
    inputScan.close();

    File dir = new File(filePath+"subnet_output");
    dir.mkdir();


    for(String myAddr: addr){
        String myFileName = myAddr.replaceAll("/", "-");

        File file = new File(dir+myFileName+".txt");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Is there anything coming after creating that `PrintWriter` or is that the end of the loop? You don't do anything with that file and that `writer`.

Comment: Why you are adding 'dir' variable while creating a file with .txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing "/" while creating file inside folder:

```
File file = new File(dir+myFileName+".txt");
```

Replace with:

```
File file = new File(dir+File.pathSeparator+myFileName+".txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `PrintWriter.append(...)` and `PrintWriter.flush()` for actually writing into that file you want to create.

Answer (score 0):

File file = new File(dir+"/"+myFileName+".txt");